# PopupMenuButton doesn't work. It changes the values but doen't rerender the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and trying to do my first assignment. I have been looking all over but can't find why PopupMenuButoon doesn't work. I use it to switch between all items and favorites only but it only changes the values and does not rerender the screen. Here is a snippet of my code.

```
enum FilterOptions {
  Favorites,
  All,
}

...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _showOnlyFavorites = false;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton(
            itemBuilder: (_) => [
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text('Only Favorites'),
                value: FilterOptions.Favorites,
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text('Show All'),
                value: FilterOptions.All,
              ),
            ],
            onSelected: (FilterOptions selectedValue) {
              setState(() {
                if (selectedValue == FilterOptions.Favorites) {
                  setState(() {
                    _showOnlyFavorites = true;
                  });
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    _showOnlyFavorites = false;
                  });
                }
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
        ...
      ),
      body: RecipesGrid(_showOnlyFavorites),

class RecipesGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  bool isFav;
  RecipesGrid(this.isFav);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final recipeData = Provider.of<RecipeProvider>(context);
    List<Recipe> recipes = isFav == false ? recipeData.recipes : recipeData.favoritesList;

    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: recipes.length,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 1,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisSpacing: 5,
        childAspectRatio: 2.3 / 1,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (context, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: recipes[i],
        child: isFav == true && recipes == []
            ? Text('You don\'t have any favorites yet. Start adding some!')
            : RecipeItem(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool _showOnlyFavorites = false;
```

This variable is *local* to your `build` method. That means it is thrown away and reinstated with it's assigned value every time the `build` function is called. For obvious reasons, having state changes saved in a variable that resets every time the state changes is not going to work.

You need to put this variable somewhere else. If this is a state class, you could put it on class level, otherwise you need some state management approach. You already seem to have a provider, so you know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use setState in Nested way. Just follow the code given below:

```
  if (selectedValue == FilterOptions.Favorites) {
              setState(() {
                _showOnlyFavorites = true;
              });
      } else {
              setState(() {
                _showOnlyFavorites = false;
              });
        }
```